# Limit scan angle with Laser Filter?

Tags: ros, laser-filters, sicklms, laser-pipeline

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using the LMS1xx node (http://www.ros.org/wiki/LMS1xx) with my LMS151-10100, and I want to limit the min angle and max angle (I have obstacles on either side of the laser).  The LMS1xx node does not currently allow you to limit the published scan angle, and it seems that isn't supported by the laser atm either.  So, I was wondering if I could use some part of the laser_pipeline to clip off angles < 0 and > 180 easily.

Nothing jumped out at me on the wiki as being able to do this.

Thanks in advance for you help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9667/limit-scan-angle-with-laser-filter?/) by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17335 on 2011-04-06

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on 2018-03-06**:
did you solve it? if you did it , could you please help me:/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're looking for the [LaserScanAngularBoundsFilter](https://dev.bdm.cc/rosdoc/laser_filters/html/classlaser__filters_1_1LaserScanAngularBoundsFilter.html). :-)

Admittedly, a list of available plugins/filters is often missing in the Wiki. So this is how I found it:

```
martin@caprica:~$ rospack plugins --attrib=plugin filters 
katana_trajectory_filter /home/martin/ros/stacks/uos-ros-pkg/katana_driver/katana_trajectory_filter/default_plugins.xml
constraint_aware_spline_smoother /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/trajectory_filters/constraint_aware_spline_smoother/default_plugins.xml
joint_normalization_filters /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/trajectory_filters/joint_normalization_filters/default_plugins.xml
spline_smoother /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/trajectory_filters/spline_smoother/default_plugins.xml
isolated_point_filter /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/navigation_experimental/isolated_point_filter/ipf_plugin.xml
assisted_teleop /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/navigation_experimental/assisted_teleop/filter_plugins.xml
pr2_navigation_perception /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/pr2_navigation/pr2_navigation_perception/config/pr2_laser_filters/pr2_laser_filters_plugins.xml
laser_tilt_controller_filter /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/pr2_navigation/laser_tilt_controller_filter/laser_tilt_controller_filter_plugins.xml
laser_filters /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/laser_pipeline/laser_filters/laser_filters_plugins.xml
filters /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/common/filters/default_plugins.xml
```

Ok, so this is a list of *all* packages that contain filters, not just the laser filters. Looks like `laser_filters` is the only interesting package. The command above gives you the path of the plugin configuration XML file, which lists all the plugins defined in that package.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3